# How do I add dynamic relational values together inside a single measure without calculated columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

This is an example that I'm using to verify my formula:

```
director    actor   date_added  show_id
x           a       2015        Meow
x           b       2015        Meow
x           a       2020        Woof
x           c       2020        Woof
y           d       1999        Moo
y           e       2002        CaCaw
z           f       2018        Bark
```

The hard part is to do with the restriction of not being able to use calculated columns, tables, or modifying the original data/queries.

From this table I need to find out the longevity for each director:

```
director    longevity
x           6
y           4
z           1
```

```
VAR DirectorLongevityTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            'table',
            [director] <> BLANK()
            && [actor] <> BLANK()
            && [show_id] <> BLANK()
        ),
        'table'[director],
        "Longevity", MAX('table'[date_added]) - MIN('table'[date_added]) + 1
    )
```

Then find the number of movies for each pairing:

```
director    actor   # of movies
x           a       2
x           b       1
x           c       1
y           d       1
y           e       1
z           f       1
```

```
VAR PairedMovieCountTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            'table',
            [director] <> BLANK()
            && [actor] <> BLANK()
            && [show_id] <> BLANK()
        ),
        'table'[actor],
        "# of movies", COUNT('table'[show_id])
    )
```

So that I can have data that looks like this:

```
director    actor   movies  longevity
x           a       2       6
x           b       1       6
x           c       1       6
y           d       1       4
y           e       1       4
z           f       1       1
```

And the final calculation should be (SUM of movies/SUM of longevity) which in this case is 7 and 27 respectively for a final average of .259

*I'm not sure how to get the "for each value in MOVIES, get their respective director's longevity and then add them all up to divide by the SUM of MOVIES).*

I've tried a number of methods, but nothing seems to work when I add more data to the table.

EDIT: corrected table name

Comment: Why is your definition for *PairedMovieCountTable* summarizing via the *cast* column (which you haven't shared, incidentally) and not also via the *director* column, as per your definition for *DirectorLongevityTable*?

Comment: cast = actor in this case, I changed some table names around from the larger project to help make it clear when asking for help and I missed one.

PairedMovieCountTable is the total number of movies each unique director/actor pair has been in. In this case it is 7 (5 unique pairs + actor a being in 2 of director x's movies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following **measure**:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            'table',
            [director] <> BLANK ()
                && [actor] <> BLANK ()
                && [show_id] <> BLANK ()
        ),
        'table'[director],
        'table'[actor],
        "Longevity",
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'table'[date_added] ) - MIN ( 'table'[date_added] ) + 1,
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'table', 'table'[director] )
            ),
        "# of movies", COUNT ( 'table'[show_id] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( SUMX ( T1, [# of movies] ), SUMX ( T1, [Longevity] ) )
```

Comment: The good news is that this works for my sample project.

The bad news is that it doesn't work with the large dataset.

But since you went ahead and answered my original post I think it's safe to mark it as completed, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is there anything else apart from size which differentiates your actual dataset from the sample dataset?

Comment: There is. It's more than just a table, but the relationships aren't abstract or anything. The only things that I can see that change is that we go by year released instead of date added for longevity and we filter by only movies.

[I made the post here if you would like to check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76145868/not-sure-why-my-answer-is-not-correct-when-calculating-relationships-in-dataset)