# Not sure why my answer is not correct when calculating relationships in dataset

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to find the average number of movies done together(as in per actor/director pair) per year of director's longevity (without modifying the original data or using calculated columns).

Thanks to the helpful people here, I have this code:

```
AvgMoviesLong = 

VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            'netflix',
            [director] <> BLANK ()
                && [cast] <> BLANK ()
                && [show_id] <> BLANK ()
                && [director] <> [cast]
                && RELATED('Content'[category]) = "Movie"
        ),
        'netflix'[director],
        'netflix'[cast],
        "Longevity",
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'Content'[release_year] ) - MIN ( 'Content'[release_year] ) + 1,
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'netflix', 'Netflix'[cast] )
            ),
        "# of movies", COUNT ( 'netflix'[cast] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( SUMX ( T1, [# of movies] ), SUMX ( T1, [Longevity] ) )
```

The problem is that the values are between 15 and 20x smaller than the correct answer. My original code came to the same answer, but was much messier so I feel like *this* is the right method, but there's another angle I haven't thought of that is causing. *I'm relatively new to DAX/Power BI so there might be something obvious I'm missing.*

Possible helpful information:

1. Current total with this calculation is 0.04, correct answer is 0.67.
2. Blanks have been filtered out for Director, Cast, and show_id.
3. We only want movies, so TV Shows are filtered out.

Comment: Actually, the code you posted has potentially crucial differences from the one I posted. Here more than one table is involved, which you should not dismiss as insignificant. Suggest you clarify the relationship between the *nextflix* and *Content* tables and also make an effort to create reduced example datasets from both tables.

Comment: There were several questions prior to this one that I had no issue finding the right answer so I felt empowered :P

[This is the schema/relationships](https://imgur.com/qLSSEWv) but most of the values here aren't being used. I haven't had an issue matching or producing calculations until this last problem.

Also, ignore the [# of Pairings], that was my own that I did to verify some previous results.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel that it's going to be difficult to help further without sample data plus expected result, as you provided in your previous post.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that here? [Are we allowed to provide links to the file?](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-qhz7RbXx5t9tyXKswpW3xHe_hergCu_/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine there must be simpler methods, though this is how I approached the problem.

```
AvgMoviesLong =
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            'netflix',
            [director] <> BLANK ()
                && [cast] <> BLANK ()
                && [show_id] <> BLANK ()
                && [director] <> [cast]
                && RELATED ( 'Content'[category] ) = "Movie"
        ),
        'netflix'[director],
        'netflix'[cast],
        "Longevity",
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'Content'[release_year] ) - MIN ( 'Content'[release_year] ) + 1,
                ALLEXCEPT ( Netflix, 'Netflix'[director] ),
                CROSSFILTER ( 'Content'[show_id], Netflix[show_id], BOTH )
            ),
        "# of movies", COUNT ( 'netflix'[cast] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( SUMX ( T1, [# of movies] ), SUMX ( T1, [Longevity] ) )
```

Comment: This worked! Now I need to reverse engineer it all to find out exactly why. You're the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
Average Movies Together = 
AVERAGEX(
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER(Netflix,Netflix[director]<>BLANK() || Netflix[cast]<>BLANK() && CONTAINSSTRING(Netflix[subcategory],"Movies")),
    Netflix[director],
    Netflix[cast],
    "No of Movies Together",DISTINCTCOUNT(Netflix[show_id])
),
  [No of Movies Together]    
)        
------------
AverageReleaseLength = 
AVERAGEX(        
    SUMMARIZE(
      FILTER(Netflix,Netflix[director] <> BLANK() && Netflix[cast] <> BLANK() &&CONTAINSSTRING(Netflix[subcategory],"Movies")),
      Netflix[director],
      Netflix[cast],
      "Min of Release Year",MIN(Netflix[Year_added]),
      "Max of Release Year",MAX(Netflix[Year_added])
    ),
    [Max of Release Year]-[Min of Release Year]+1
)
```

---

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).